# Is there any Difference between YARN and MR2?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2

I am bit confused between `YARN` and `MR2`. are they same ? I have seen `YARN` as platform for running distributed application in some documentations and MapReduce as such distributed appication, What is meant by that ? Is that a `MapReduce` application built by a programmer(eg : `wordcount` program) ? 
Again I have seen like 'Writing your own `YARN` application ', what is meant by that ? Which category a wordcount program belongs, a `YARN` application or a `MR2` application ?

Please corret question if its not in the stackoverflow standard , I was trying to express all my doubts.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly YARN introduced in HADOOP 2 onward.In hadoop 1, a single Name node managed the entire namespace for a Hadoop cluster.With the introduction of YARN(YET ANOTHER RESOURCE MANAGER) cluster resource management is taken care by YARN.

You can assume that YARN runs above HDFS and on the YARN different data processing component like mapreduce and othes run.
In Hadoop 1, users had the option of writing MapReduce programs in Java, in Python, or other scripting languages using streaming, or using Pig, a data transformation language. Regardless of which method was used, all fundamentally relied on the MapReduce processing model to run.

YARN supports multiple processing models in addition to MapReduce. One of the most significant benefits of this is that we are no longer limited to working the often I/O intensive, high latency MapReduce framework.

Now your question- 'Writing your own YARN application ', what is meant by that ?

Now on YARN we can write any of the distributed application. MR2 is one of that distributed application that is responsible for running MapReduce framework.So word count program belongs to MR2 application which is responsible to run this mapreduce frmework.

Answer (score 0):

`YARN` and `MR2` are related, but not the same.

`MapReduce` is a computational approach, and in the Hadoop world, `MapReduce` is also a name synonymous for Hadoop 1.0; in Hadoop 1.0, `MapReduce` provided both resource management and the execution framework for running "MapReduce" (1.0) applications

With Hadoop 2.0, resource management and the execution framework were split to be two separate entities, `YARN` (Yet Another Resource Negotiator) a general resource management system for cluster compute resources, and `MapReduce 2.0` (abbreviated as `MR2`) an execution engine.

- `MR2` is a `YARN` application
- You can write a "MapReduce" (2.0) based application that will run on `YARN`
- If you are on a Hadoop 2.0 cluster and use something like `Pig` or `Hive` with the default execution engine, `MR2`, they will run as `MR2` applications on `YARN`

Part of the reasoning for this split in Hadoop 2.0 was to allow for other execution engines, beyond `MR2`; today this also includes Apache `Tez` and Apache `Spark`, which can run on `YARN`.